# Getting Unexpected token, expected if json file imported in JS file with yarn test using Jest

Tags: jestjs

In one of my js file below code is present

```
let FieldMapping import('index.json').then((f) => {   FieldMapping = f })
```

after running yarn test, i am getting below error:

> Unexpected token, expected { (10:6)
>          8 |
>          9 | let FieldMapping
>
> > 10 | import('index.json').then((f) => {
> >              |       ^
> >           11 |   FieldMapping = f
> >           12 | })

I have added below configuration in "**moduleNameMapper**" but still issue is exist.

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(scss|json)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, I found that when I put:

`"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }`

In package.json it did not work, but it did when I put it in my existing jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
  ...
};
```

Also have you installed identity-obj-proxy, it could be missing from package.json?